# Multi-dimensional array construction problem

Tags: javascript, arrays

I created an array (`roomsmatrixtemp[]`) of 5 elements (key value) that are stored as an element of an other array (`roomsmatrix`). Well something like collection of objects.

My code:

```
case 'roomsform':
  var roomsmatrixtemp = [];
  var roomsmatrix = [];
  var roomchild = 0;
  if (document.getElementsByClassName("newroomarea").length > 0) {
    fdataname = document.getElementsByClassName("newroomlabel");
    fdatatext = document.getElementsByClassName("newroomnametext");
    //create matric with rooms fields ----- roomchild[0] is title
    for (roomchild = 0; roomchild < document.getElementsByClassName("newroomarea").length; roomchild++) {
      for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        var name = fdataname[i + (roomchild * 5)].innerHTML; // 5 labels per room
        var text = fdatatext[i + (roomchild * 5)].innerHTML; // 5 fields per room
        roomsmatrixtemp[name] = text; // constact matrix for default room
      }
      roomsmatrix[roomchild] = roomsmatrixtemp; //add default room matrix to roomsmatrix -- roomsmatrix[x]= array for room x
    }
  }
  if (checknewform(formid)) { // check in form if room is declared
    var roomsmatrixtemp2 = [];
    for (j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
      roomform = document.getElementById("roomsform");
      roomfieldlabel = $("#roomsform .form-group label")[j];
      var name = roomfieldlabel.innerHTML;
      var text = finput[j].value; // 5 fields per room
      roomsmatrixtemp2[name] = text; // constact matrix for default room
    }
    roomsmatrix[roomchild] = roomsmatrixtemp2; //add default room matrix to roomsmatrix -- roomsmatrix[x]= array for room x}
    if (roomsmatrix.length < 1) {
      alert("No rooms declared");
    } // no rooms anywhere
    break;
```

Everything works ok BUT...  when I store the array (`roomsmatrixtemp`) with new elements in the other array (e.g `roomsmatrix[1]`) all  elements of second array become equal to the new added.

I mean that `roomsmatrix[0]=roomsmatrix[1]=roomsmatrixtemp`, although in every loop of `roomchild`, `roommatrixtemp` has different values.

Comment: You only have one `roomsmatrixtemp`. You're modifying it each time through the loop, not making a new array.

Comment: Put `roomsmatrixtemp = [];` inside the loop.

Comment: Just like you do with `roomsmatrixtemp2` in the second loop.

Comment: yes what i supposed to do is to save all modifications in an other array. i mean after every modification i stored it, but that changes all stored modifications.. That's the problem...

Comment: Storing it doesn't make a copy of the array. So all elements of `roomsmatrix` are references to the same `roomsmatrixtemp` array.

Comment: Yes my friend.. that worked exactly as i want it.  Thank you very much for your help... keep well..